# Resume - Multiple positions at same company

Tags: resume

On my resume, how would I go about displaying that I held multiple titles at the same institution?

Some examples of what I'm talking about:

1. In university, I was a computer lab supervisor (hiring/firing students to staff a lab and create the weekly schedules, address performance, etc), a peer tutor (working independently helping students with CS classes underneath a distant manager), and I worked
   at the IT service desk (on-site classroom tech support, then got a promotion after a year), all at the same time. All different
   titles/responsibilities/reporting managers, but all at the same company (my college).
2. After college, I got hired on somewhere else as a Dev, was promoted to Senior Developer, all at the
   same position/department/company
3. In the same company as 2, but did a lateral move to a different
   department with radically different responsibilities & technologies (Oracle packaged app production support vs full stack web developer doing long-term build/project work),
   but technically the same title of Sr Dev and same company as 2

Comment: It's going to depend very much on the content, how much overlap there was in the responsibilities and achievements, whether the dates overlapped and what the rest of your resume looks like - you can list them on the same line (as long as that doesn't make the line too long), on consecutive lines or you can completely separate them out into different sections. There isn't really one perfect way to do things, it depends on what would showcase your experience in the best way.

Comment: @darkcygnus looked for that, couldn't find it

Comment: @HorusKol yeah, I also thought I have seen this Q before... guess my Google Fu is strong today :)

Comment: I've edited to show the (major, imo) differences between jobs and why it's not just a linear progression at one company like the suggested duplicate, nor just added responsibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're a senior developer, I'll assume you graduated several years ago.

Unless you're looking to move back to more of a support tech or tutoring role and away from development, your experience in 1 is likely to be mostly irrelevant to future employers. List the titles and go directly to 2.

For 2 - list the dates you were a dev. Write a paragraph covering the work you did and the technology/languages used. Then list the senior dev role from 2 and 3 under one set of dates. Write a paragraph covering the role and responsiblities in 2, and another paragraph covering the move to a different team/projects in 3.

Remember - keep to the highlights and demonstrate how the relevant skills and knowledge for the role you are applying for were applied in your previous roles.

> Computer Lab Supervisor / Peer Tutor / IT Services
>   Alma Mater College
>   12/2012 - 12/2013
>
> Developer
>   12/2013 - 06/2016
>   Alma Mater College
>
> Worked in a team to...
>
> Senior Developer
>   06/2016 - now
>   Alma Mater College
>
> Led development on...

Comment: I think this addresses everything! One question though--I feel like it would be misleading to combine my Sr Dev job dates together because it doesn't show how much experience I have in each particular tech (absolutely no overlap in them, and I'm fairly new to the more recent one). Should I just split them out into their own sections??

Comment: Exactly what techs/languages are we talking about? I suppose you could split it as Senior Dev - Tech 1, and Senior Dev - Tech 2 roles

Comment: One was production support in Peoplesoft, one is project-based full stack web dev (Angular, JS, Java, etc.) That makes sense, thanks!